# How to extract frames from video faster?

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, video

Currently, I am retrieving video frames based on the following code:

```
# Retrieve Images from Videos
for video in list_videos:
    vidcap = cv2.VideoCapture(video)
    success, image = vidcap.read()
    count = 0
    print("Successfully retrieving videos from ", video)
    while success:
        cv2.imwrite('.'+video.split('.')[-2]+'/'+'frame%d.png' %count, image)
        success, image = vidcap.read()
        count += 1
    vidcap.release()
```

This code is taking a lot of time to extract the frames from videos. Is there a faster way to implement this code?

Answer (score 1):

The line of code that takes the most time is:

```
cv2.imwrite('.'+video.split('.')[-2]+'/'+'frame%d.png' %count, image)
```

One way to make that line faster is to resize the image (make it smaller) before writing it to the hard drive:

```
cv2.resize(image, (640,480))
```

Another way to process the video more quickly would be to write the images to the memory instead of the hard drive. This method will work only if you have enough RAM to hold the images. It could lead to a catastrophic computer crash:

```
images = []
while success:
    images.append(image)
    success, image = video.read()
```

Comment: Thanks for the inputs. I will try the first option. It's a huge data so I am leaving the second option. Is there a way to cv2.imwrite() step